# How to use the dplyr library to select specific variables and then match a variable with a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, match

I need to use the `filter` function in `dplyr` to retrieve all values in which my variable entitled `Interaction_Type` is equal to "Print"; however the code below is not retrieving anything from my data frame `df1` other than listing the variables with 'Interaction.ID','Name.ID','Created.At' with no values at all:

```r
df2 <- df1 %>% select (c('Interaction.ID','Name.ID','Created.At','Interaction_Type'))
           %>% filter ('Interaction_Type' == "print")
```

Should I use the `match()` function instead?

Comment: Try without the single quotes around Interaction: `filter(Interaction == "print")`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, post as answer? (For a reproducible example, compare `filter(mtcars, 'cyl' == 6)` and `filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)` ...)

Comment: it works without single quote, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `filter()` function is expecting a variable name (without quotes) rather than a string.  Removing the quotes from around Interaction will solve the problem.  Consider the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% filter("cyl" == 4)
#>  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

In the example above, no results are returned because there is no instance where the string `"cyl"` is equals the number 4. In the code below, filter is trying to find the cases where the variable `cyl` equals 4 - this is the desired result.

```r
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>